# Claiming tax loss after selling US mutual fund using specific lots

Tags: united-states, taxes, mutual-funds, vanguard

Background:

---

I want to sell one mutual fund that I own in Vanguard to claim a tax loss on it. The default cost basis offered in Vanguard is "Average Cost" method. But I calculated that if I use the spec id method, I would be able to claim a greater tax loss. So I have updated the cost basis method in Vanguard to use specific lot id for selling the fund.

Vanguard is not able to show lot id for shares that I had purchased before 2012. Though I am able to get this information from the transaction history. If I continue to sell the shares, Vanguard states that it will report only the average cost basis to IRS.

My questions are:

---

1. Will I be able to use the specific shares cost basis for shares bought previous to 2012, if Vanguard reports only the average cost basis to IRS?
2. If I am allowed to use the spec lot id method, how should I inform IRS when filing taxes next year about the cost basis that I calculated using specific shares?
3. What kind of documentation will I need to provide as proof for the specific share cost basis calculation?
4. If I want to buy back the same fund and avoid it being categorized as a wash sale, according to IRS rules for wash sales, I need to wait for at least 30 days. When does this 30 day period start? How would it get affected if I sell shares over multiple days versus in a single day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will I be able to use the specific shares cost basis for shares bought
>   previous to 2012, if Vanguard reports only the average cost basis to
>   IRS?

Yes.

> If I am allowed to use the spec lot id method, how should I inform IRS
>   when filing taxes next year about the cost basis that I calculated
>   using specific shares?

It should appear on your tax return, Schedule D and the associated forms.

> What kind of documentation will I need to provide as proof for the
>   specific share cost basis calculation?

If asked, you need to be able to show all the transactions for this fund. Once you use specific lot - you have to keep using specific lots.

> If I want to buy back the same fund and avoid it being categorized as
>   a wash sale, according to IRS rules for wash sales, I need to wait for
>   at least 30 days. When does this 30 day period start? How would it get
>   affected if I sell shares over multiple days versus in a single day?

It starts on the date of the sale at loss, and goes into both directions. I.e.: you cannot buy 30 days **before or after** the sale at loss. If you have multiple sales, there's 30 days period (both directions) for **each**, which may or may not overlap.

Comment: so this would mean the period for preventing wash sales is actually 60 days? 30 days before and 30 days after the sale claiming loss?

Comment: @EndlessSpace yes